# ASP.NET MVC and LLBLGEN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orm, llblgen

Anybody aware of a best practices or example project out there that uses ASP.NET MVC and LLBLGEN (selfservicing or adaptor)? Possibly something similar to S#arp Architecture.

I'm new to MVC and I'm constrained to using LLBLGEN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this thread on our forum for additional templates to make this easy:
http://www.llblgen.com/tinyforum/Messages.aspx?ThreadID=17343

Answer (score 3):

I would love to see a detailed answer to this question, specially highlighting the Adapter model in LLBLGen.

my implementation is by far not necessary "best practice", but works in a real life scenario.

I used:

- LLBLGen Self Servicing in business objects.
- ModelView (MV) objects in ASP.NET MVC
- AutoMapper to "flat" llblgen entities to modelviews.
- StructureMap to control the bloating :)

ref: [AutoMapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper)

Comment: I recently completed a MVC/LLBL project with a very similar approach.  However, I'm curious what you meant by flattening the llblgen entities.  Does this mean you took the relational entities and put them in a tabular data structure like a datatable?

Comment: I'm assuming you both had to create your own BL layer. Is the following an accurate picture of your project architecture. project.BL (manually created), project.DAL (llblgen generated), project.MVC (controllers, views). I assume you passed llblgen entities between the projects/layers/tiers. What about validation? Anything cool done here (xVal, etc...)?

Comment: We started with adapter and I kind of wish we could have used self-servicing (to make our model more domain driven).  Alas, we needed it to be cross-database, so there was no other option.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you read some of the articles about implimenting (for instance) NHibernate in ASP.NET MVC?  Unless LLBLGEN takes a completely different approach (and I'm not sure that it doesn't, but would be very suprised) then the principles will be very similar.  In other words, it won't of course teach you how to use LLBLGEN, but will give you some best practices for ORM use with MVC.

There are some articles for instance here: http://nhforge.org/